# Use one data-frame (used as a dictionary) to fill in the main data-frame (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a central DataFrame called "cases" (5000000 rows × 5 columns) and a secondary DataFrame, called "relevant information", which is a kind of dictionary in relation to the central DataFrame (300 rows × 6 columns).
I am trying to fill in the central DataFrame based on a common column called "Verdict_type".
And, if the value does not appear in the secondary DataFrame it fill in "not_relevant" in all the rows that will be added.
I used all sorts of directions without success.
I would love to get a good direction.

[The DataFrames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ersln.png)

Comment: Please provide code e data.

Comment: To clear this out, do you want to move the data from the main ("cases") data frame to either "relevant information" data frame or "not_relevant" data frame, based on the common column "Verdict_type"?

Comment: I want to use the "DataFrame Dictionary" (secondary DataFrame) to add information to the main DataFrame.. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# this is a mockup of the raw data
cases = [
    [1, "1", "v1"],
    [2, "2", "v2"],
    [3, "3", "v3"]
]

relevant_info = [
    ["v1", "info1"],
    ["v3", "info3"]
]

# these are the data from screenshot
df_cases = pd.DataFrame(cases, columns=["id", "verdict_name", "verdict_type"]).set_index("id")
df_relevant_info = pd.DataFrame(relevant_info, columns=["verdict_type", "features"])
```

Input:
[df_cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE48Q.png) <-- note here the index marked as 'id'
[df_relevant_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQPh.png)

```
# first, flatten the index of the cases ( this is probably what you were missing )
df_cases = df_cases.reset_index()
# then, merge the two sets on the verdict_type
df_merge = pd.merge(df_cases, df_relevant_info, on="verdict_type", how="outer")
# finally, mark missing values as non relevant
df_merge["features"] = df_merge["features"].fillna(value="not_relevant")
```

Output:

```
merged set:
+----+------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|    |   id |   verdict_name | verdict_type   | features     |
|----+------+----------------+----------------+--------------|
|  0 |    1 |              1 | v1             | info1        |
|  1 |    2 |              2 | v2             | not_relevant |
|  2 |    3 |              3 | v3             | info3        |
+----+------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked..
My mistake was: (how="outer")